# Adding a new group to user - java.lang.UnsupporterOperationException for a List that is not accepting the adding in herself

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am currently building an application based on the SantaSecret (or drawnames) and this app is currently in the testing phase.
The application is using Hibernate and JPA.
My project is built with a ManyToMany relations between the entity "Users" and the entity "SecretSantaGroup".
I want to add a new group to the user and update the user list of groups as well, but while trying to add the creator of the group in the group newly created, i'm getting the following error :

Solved ! Here is the changes i made : 
I started to manually add Getters to overpass the immutable ArrayLists :

Users and SecretSantaGroup :

```
 public List<SecretSantaGroup> getGroups() {
        if (groups == null) {
            groups = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return groups;
    }

    public List<Users> getMembers() {
        if (members == null) {
            members = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return members;
    }
```

And i changed my create method to this, with the adding line change :

```
 public SecretSantaGroup createSecretSantaGroup(SecretSantaGroup secretSantaGroup, UUID creatorId) {
        try {
            secretSantaGroupRepository.save(secretSantaGroup);
            // Validate if the creator user has the appropriate role (admin)
            Users creator = userRepository.findById(creatorId)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new SecretSantaGroupException("User not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
            creator.setRole(Role.ADMIN);

            // Define the group creator as admin
            secretSantaGroup.setAdmin(creator);
            String uniqueUrl = generateUniqueGroupUrl(secretSantaGroup.getName(), secretSantaGroup.getId());
            secretSantaGroup.setUrl(uniqueUrl);

            // Add the creator as a group member
            SecretSantaGroup createdGroup = secretSantaGroupRepository.save(secretSantaGroup);
            This line : createdGroup.setMembers(userRepository.findAllById(Collections.singleton(creatorId)));

            secretSantaGroupRepository.save(createdGroup);
            userRepository.save(creator);

            if (!creator.getRole().equals(Role.ADMIN)) {
                throw new SecretSantaGroupException("User does not have the appropriate role to create a group", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            }

            // Add the groups in the List of groups of the creator
            creator.getGroups().add(createdGroup);
            userRepository.save(creator);

            if (createdGroup.getId() == null) {
                throw new SecretSantaGroupException("Failed to create Secret Santa Group: group id is null", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
            return createdGroup;
        } catch (DataAccessException | ConstraintViolationException e) {
            throw new SecretSantaGroupException("Failed to create Secret Santa Group: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

```
2023-05-04T13:05:29.534+02:00 ERROR 12272 --- [nio-5757-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException] with root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:155) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:113) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag.add(PersistentBag.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at com.santa.work.entity.SecretSantaGroup.addMember(SecretSantaGroup.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.santa.work.service.secretSantaGroup.SecretSantaGroupServiceImpl.createSecretSantaGroup(SecretSantaGroupServiceImpl.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at com.santa.work.service.secretSantaGroup.SecretSantaGroupServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$1.createSecretSantaGroup(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at com.santa.work.service.secretSantaGroup.SecretSantaGroupServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createSecretSantaGroup(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.santa.work.controller.SecretSantaGroupController.createSecretSantaGroup(SecretSantaGroupController.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
```

Also, here are the files defined in the error and other ones to give you more context :

Users :

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "UUID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="UUID", sequenceName = "sequence_user", allocationSize = 1)
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "id_user", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private UUID id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="lastname", nullable = false)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="login", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String login;

    @Column(name="password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name ="email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Wish> wishList = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "members", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SecretSantaGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invitedUser")
    private Set<Invitation> invitations;

    public void addGroup(SecretSantaGroup group) {
        groups.add(group);
        group.getMembers().add(this);
    }
}
```

SecretSantaGroup :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "santa_group")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SecretSantaGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="UUID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="UUID", sequenceName = "sequence_santa")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name ="id_santa_group", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "secret_santa_group_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "admin_id")
    private Users admin;

    @Column(name = "group_url", unique = true)
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "matches_generated", nullable = false)
    private boolean matchesGenerated = false;

    //List des membres du groupe
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "group_members",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    )
    private List<Users> members = new ArrayList<>();

    //List invitation groupe secretsanta, invitation liée à un groupe
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Invitation> invitations = new ArrayList<>();

    //Liste de correspondance pour membre de chaque groupe, match associé à un groupe santa spécifique
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Match> matches = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addInvitation(Invitation invitation) {
        invitations.add(invitation);
        invitation.setGroup(this);
    }
    public void addMatch(Match match) {
        matches.add(match);
        match.setGroup(this);
    }
    public boolean allInvitationsAccepted() {
        for (Invitation invitation : this.invitations) {
            if (invitation.getStatus() != InvitationStatus.ACCEPTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void addMember(Users user) {
        this.members.add(user);
        user.addGroup(this);
    }
}
```

The method to create (messy i know but I'm improving !)

```
 public SecretSantaGroup createSecretSantaGroup(SecretSantaGroup secretSantaGroup, UUID creatorId) {
        try {
            secretSantaGroupRepository.save(secretSantaGroup);
            // Validate if the creator user has the appropriate role (admin)
            Users creator = userRepository.findById(creatorId)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new SecretSantaGroupException("User not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
            creator.setRole(Role.ADMIN);

            // Define the group creator as admin
            secretSantaGroup.setAdmin(creator);
            String uniqueUrl = generateUniqueGroupUrl(secretSantaGroup.getName(), secretSantaGroup.getId());
            secretSantaGroup.setUrl(uniqueUrl);

            // Add the creator as a group member
            secretSantaGroup.addMember(creator);

            SecretSantaGroup createdGroup = secretSantaGroupRepository.save(secretSantaGroup);

            if (!creator.getRole().equals(Role.ADMIN)) {
                throw new SecretSantaGroupException("User does not have the appropriate role to create a group", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            }

            // Add the groups in the List of groups of the creator
            creator.getGroups().add(createdGroup);
            userRepository.save(creator);

            if (createdGroup.getId() == null) {
                throw new SecretSantaGroupException("Failed to create Secret Santa Group: group id is null", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
            return createdGroup;
        } catch (DataAccessException | ConstraintViolationException e) {
            throw new SecretSantaGroupException("Failed to create Secret Santa Group: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance, and due to my karma i might not be able to upvote your answer or answer it

Comment: what is the actual line of code you get an error?

Comment: Hi @Stultuske, the actual error i'm getting an error on is :             secretSantaGroup.addMember(creator) in my createSecretSantaGroup method

Comment: I i can add another comment, the add basic method was throwing the exact same error

Comment: yes, I get that, but to what line of your code causes the issue? have you debugged your code?

Comment: It's this particular line
The creator have the full Users objet in it, but the debugger is running indefinitely while passing this particular line, could be the issue ...

Comment: saying "it's this particular line" without showing an actual line isn't all that helpful, I'm afraid

Comment: Sorry ! I thought i had pasted it in.
To be more precise, this is the following line :             secretSantaGroup.addMember(creator); 
who's causing the infinite loop in the debugger, also, it's using the normal add method but with different methods in my entities :   

 public void addGroup(SecretSantaGroup group) {
        groups.add(group);
        group.addMember(this);
    }

    public void addMember(Users user) {
        this.members.add(user);
        user.addGroup(this);
    }

I do not know what else to say about it ...

Comment: just follow the code that is triggered there. you are calling method a from method b, and method b from method a, that is what is causing your loop